# How does loadHTMLString in WKWebView work?

Tags: swift, ios8, wkwebview

I am working on a simple SWIFT app which loads a single page app from local file. When the app is launching, I use this code:

```
self.webView!.loadHTMLString("<html><body>1</body></html>", baseURL:"http://www.ft.com")
```

It works fine and the page is displayed. But when I later trigger another code in the same view:

```
self.webView!.loadHTMLString("<html><body>2</body></html>", baseURL:"http://www.ft.com")
```

The page doesn't change at all. I checked Apple's official guide but it is very vague. Could anyone explain how loadHTMLString in more detail?

Comment: 1. the webview! isn't nil? 2. do you have any delegates?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the html string you wrote is valid HTML code.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise It's valid. WebKit will display anything.

Comment: @Daij-Djan The web view can't be nil, because the program would crash when unwrapping the optional.

Comment: @akashivskyy right. nil. optionals. unwrapping -- sorry after objC, swift is still a bit alien.

Comment: The question about delegates is valid though

Comment: @akashivskyy Yes, WebKit will display it but for me the <head> informations are missing.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Yes, you're totally right, it wouldn't pass the W3C Validation. But we're takling about a `WKWebView` here. :)